# How to create two tables with same column definition in one script in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I have two scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    Id INT,
    Age INT,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(20),
    LastName NVARCHAR(20),
    Email VARCHAR(30),
    Phone VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE _Customers
(
    Id INT,
    Age INT,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(20),
    LastName NVARCHAR(20),
    Email VARCHAR(30),
    Phone VARCHAR(20)
)
```

The only difference is the table name.

How to replace 2 column definitions with one? So not to have errors in the future in case of renaming a column or adding a new column to one table (tables always have to be equally defined)?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What's the DBMS? And why not just using one table with an additional column that indicates whether a row is a `_` customer or not?

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It might be worth taking a step backwards. What problem will you be solving by having two tables that are almost identical apart from an indicator in the table name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, if you want to create a new table with the same column names and types, you can use:

```
select c.*
into _customer
from customer c
where 1 = 0;
```

You might want to drop `_customer` before doing this.

Note:  This does not copy constraints or triggers, so it is not an alternative to `create table like` that is available in other databases.  But your question seems to be about columns and types.

Also:  `age` is a horrible value to store into a table.  It literally changes every day.

Comment: Comment on [Age] spot on.

Answer (score 1):

in oracle

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);
```

as you updated question so sql server it will be

```
SELECT * INTO newtable
FROM oldtable
WHERE condition
```